# Code Smell in Unit Testing Serialized Classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance, serialization

I can feel that something is wrong with my code. Here's an excerpt where I think the code smell is...

```
    internal Hazen(IRawDataReceiver rawDataReceiver) : base(rawDataReceiver)
    {
        SerialPortConnection = rawDataReceiver as SerialPortConnection;
    }
    private SerialPortConnection _serialPortConnection;
    [DataMember] private SerialPortConnection SerialPortConnection
    {
        get
        {
            return _serialPortConnection;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value != null)
            {
                _serialPortConnection = value;
                RawDataReceiver = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically, `Hazen` inherits from an abstract class. Notice how I pass the `rawDataReceiver` to its `base class` when `Hazen`'s `constructor` is called. But during `deserialization`, the `constructor` is **bypassed**, thus I included the `RawDataReceiver = value` to the `set` accessor of the `DataMember property`. That is where the code smell is. Is there a better way to do it and am I violating any good practices (such as `DRY`)?

As regards to `unit testing`. As you can see, `Hazen` has a `property` of `type` `SerialPortConnection` as opposed to having it as `IRawDataReceiver` since you **can't** `serialize` an `interface`. Now, I can still test this class since the `base class` exposes everything I need for testing. But going back to the previous paragraph, I feel like I'm doing something wrong here.

EDIT: Here's a snippet of the base class

```
    internal TideDevice(IRawDataReceiver rawDataReceiver)
    {
        RawDataReceiver = rawDataReceiver;
    }
    private IRawDataReceiver _rawDataReceiver;
    protected internal IRawDataReceiver RawDataReceiver
    {
        get
        {
            return _rawDataReceiver;
        }
        protected set
        {
            _rawDataReceiver = value;
            RawDataReceiver.RawDataReceived += RawDataReceiver_RawDataReceived;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I have extracted the `Task` to another method to remove the responsibility of the `set` accessor. But I'm still in a roadblock on fixing the code smell I initially stated. I editted the code to reflect what I have now.

EDIT2: This code is working really fine whether in `unit test` and `integration test`, so I'll leave it as is until someone points out that there is something wrong here or until a problem arises. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is your intention to write an "R" to the serial port whenever this class is constructed or deserialized? Why?

Comment: "R" is a fixed string needed to interrogate the other end of the device the serial port is communicating to. It's outside of the code's scope.

Comment: @200_success base class posted. As you can see, I can `mock` the `IRawDataReceiver` since the `base class` has that `type` as its member. So it kind of complements the restriction on the  `subclass`  with respect to `serialization`

Comment: @200_success When the class is constructed/deserialized, I want it to immediately interrogate the device it needs to communicate to thus I placed the `Task` within the `set` accessor too.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some thinking, this is now the final code for the `Hazen` class.. the `abstract/base` class `TideDevice` stays the same.

```
internal Hazen(IRawDataReceiver rawDataReceiver) : base(rawDataReceiver)
{
    _serialPortConnection = rawDataReceiver as SerialPortConnection;
}
[DataMember] private SerialPortConnection _serialPortConnection;

[OnDeserialized] private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext sc)
{
    RawDataReceiver = _serialPortConnection;
}
```

So as you can see, the `[OnDeserialized]` method will act as the `constructor` after `deserialization`. Or more specifically, it mimics the `base(rawDataReceiver)` part of "actual" `constructor`.

That's it. Thanks @jeyoung and @JNS.

Answer (score 2):

I think the bigger issue is that you have an operation with side-effect in the property setter `SerialPortConnection`,  which means that if your unit test fails, it will not be clear whether it is due to a problem with deserialisation or with the operation.

I would suggest moving the operation (i.e. writing "R" to the port) in a separate `Initialize` method that you can test individually.

Comment: Actually, the 'Task' was initially in a separate 'Initialize' method. I decided to include it to the 'setter' since I found myself always calling the 'Initialize' after the 'deserialization'. Though I get your point and would consider removing the 'Task' in the 'setter' accesor. Thanks!

Comment: To re-assure you, it is quite normal to construct an object in several stages (calling the constructor, then setting the properties). In OO, the responsibility and rules of constructing an object rest with the "builder" (that is, you). The only catch is that you need to make sure that the building happens in only one place and according to your construction rules, say, a Factory method.

Comment: I find it funny that what you just said was my initial approach where I have a 'factory' method and it calls the 'Initialize' method after constructing the object. :))

Comment: At the risk of sounding presumptuous, I was in this situation, too, early in my career when a lack of validation of my ideas drove me to go back and forth between good and bad solutions. If you are interested in good design, I would recommend learning about state machines and stick with it until the penny drops.

Comment: I've made quite a few refactors now into this program alone, I guess it's part of learning. :) I'm interested on learning about state machines. could you recommend some books/sites/references where I could start? Thanks!

Comment: I highly recommend [How to Build Shlaer-Mellor Object Models](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/189-7186769-2842529?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=leon+starr). It is a very old publication (in tech-years) and the notations used are outdated and have been replaced by UML, but the foundations are still valid. I like to think the prices of these old books reflect their relevance. In fact, grab everything from Leon Starr and also this much [denser book about MBD](http://www.amazon.com/Lahman-ModelBased-Development-Greg-Eakman/dp/032150920X/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8).

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much! I'll be refactoring my code again and if it looks fine, I'll be marking this as final answer. Thanks again!

Comment: please see my edit. `set` accessor looks better now. But I can't still solve my initial concern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39678/discussion-between-jeyoung-and-paolo-go).

Answer (score 1):

- You pass the `rawDataReceiver` instance to the base class via `base(rawDataReceiver)`. That will attach the event handler by the setter. In setter of property `SerialPortConnection`, the `rawDataReceiver` is set again to the base class's property `RawDataReceiver` and the event handler is added a second time. To avoid that, remove the setter of `RawDataReceiver`, assign the value (and attach the event handler) in constuctor of the base class and make the field `_rawDataReceiver` readonly.
- In constructor of `Hazen`, you assume, that the passed object is of type 'SerialPortConnection'. If that is always the case, you can change the type of the constructor argument to `SerialPortConnection`. If that is not always the case, you get a NRE when trying to set the base class's `DataReceiver` property.

Comment: As per your first advice, if I put those codes in the 'constructor', it will not get called during 'deserialization' in where I would need to rewrite those codes somewhere to get it called (e.g. '[OnDeserialized]')..

Comment: As per your 2nd advice, I have three things... 1.) If I make the 'constructor' argument as type 'SerialPortConnection', I will not be able to 'mock' it during test... 2.) I need to put a 'null' checker for the 'set' accessor to avoid 'NRE' in base class... 3.) With number 2 done, if I pass any implementation (e.g. 'mock') of 'IRawDataReceiver' to 'construct' 'Hazen',  my 'base' class will still have that implementation but 'Hazen' will not. Though that's ok since all I need to test are exposed in the 'base' class

Comment: @PaoloGO: If you want to test your base class, your could implement a sub class just for testing. IMHO if Hazen does only work with a special classs, there is no reason to allow to pass an abstraction because it hides the fact that Hazen could not handle other implementations.

Comment: I beg to disagree. there is a reason, `mock`. And classes depending on `IO` classes, such as `SerialPort`, should have a way to accept a `mock` for it.